# Using Joins To Retrieve Data Twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zen-cart

I have the following two MySQL queries.

$delivery_id =

```
    select c.countries_id 
           from orders o
           LEFT JOIN countries c
           ON c.countries_name = o.delivery_country
           where o.orders_id = 1208;
```

$billing_id =

```
    select c.countries_id 
           from orders o
           LEFT JOIN countries c
           ON c.countries_name = o.billing_country
           where o.orders_id = 1208;
```

With the results being put into the variables (PHP) as appropriate. What I would like to know is, is there a way to combine these two queries into one singular query instead of running it twice. (This is using ZenCart's Query Factory (`$db->Execute`) where the results will be put into a `fields` array and recalled as such.

Info about the tables: Each order in `orders` will contain a billing and delivery address with a country name being found in the appropriate field (`billing_country` and `delivery_country`). However, not all orders will contain a delivery address. How can I combine these two into one query? I know that I can use a LEFT JOIN of some sort but am not sure on how to write it.

Comment: Is billing_country required (i.e. a not null column)?

Comment: No `billing_country` can be left as NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the countries table two times using different alias names:

```
select 
    c1.countries_id AS delivering_id,
    c2.countries_id AS billing_id
from orders o
LEFT JOIN countries c1
     ON c1.countries_name = o.delivery_country
LEFT JOIN countries c2
     ON c2.countries_name = o.billing_country
where o.orders_id = 1208;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use union operator as ,

```
 select c.countries_id 
           from orders o
           LEFT JOIN countries c
           ON c.countries_name = o.delivery_country
           where o.orders_id = 1208
 UNION

 select c.countries_id 
           from orders o
           LEFT JOIN countries c
           ON c.countries_name = o.billing_country
           where o.orders_id = 1208;
```

Comment: This partially works, only that it returns the results as two rows. Is there a way to do this so that I get two columns instead?

Comment: `list($first, $second) = $db->fetchTwoRows($sql);`